# What is the difference between "look", "see", and "watch"?

Tags: difference, meaning, synonyms

When should I use "look", "see", and "watch"?

> *I'm **watching** "Star Trek".*
>   *Have you **seen** "Star Trek"?*

Are the examples above correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are some simple rules that will help deciding which word to use:

- **See** is used as *inactive word*; you just see without any effort:

  - you have visual impression: *"I can **see** my home over there"*, *"I **see** trees of green"*
  - you understand: *"I **see** what you mean"*
- **Look** is used as *active word*, you make an effort to see:

  - you **try** to see: *"look at this!"* (maybe you have to turn your head or stand up)
  - you pay an attention: *"to **look for** a baby"*
  - you search for something: *"you can **look up** the word in the dictionary"*
- **Watch** is also an *active word*; you also make an effort, but it is for a longer period of time:

  - *"I'm **watching** "Star Trek"*, *"I like to go to a zoo and **watch** tigers playing"*
  - pay attention: ***Watch*** the kittens as they may run away.

Here's an example demonstrating the difference:

> *I'm **looking**, but I don't **see** it.*

Back to examples:
*I'm **watching** "Star Trek"* — it is a continuous action;
*Have you **seen** "Star Trek"?* — it is a question if you ever seen it at all, or do you *know* about it;
It can be also formulated: *Have you **watched** "Star Trek" all night?*, and it will mean that you have *spent* all night watching a movie.

See also: [(1)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76022/26446), [(2)](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-see-look-watch.htm).

Comment: and "I looked at the screen to see what John was watching."

Comment: '+1', Nice answer. I was _looking_ for the difference, and find your answer :-)

Comment: So can you watch a picture or a statue?

Comment: To watch a picture or statue sounds strange. You look at it, you don't watch it. "Have you seen "Star Trek"? — it is a question if you [have] ever seen it at all, or do you know about it."
So in this case, it's best to ask, "Have you ever watched 'Star Trek?'"

Comment: NB readers!!! *Watch* is used for things that move or change.