# "Watch movie [x]" vs "see movie [x]"

Tags: word-choice

Is this sentence correct?

> *"I am <strike>confused</strike> undecided about whether to see movie x or y".*

Should I use *watch* here, or is *see* correct?

Comment: Either one might work, but *confused* doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: Seems to me that "see a movie" implies going to a theater, e.g. "We went to see Star Wars last night", while "watch a movie" sort of implies that you're watching at home on a TV.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "look", "see", and "watch"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/444/what-is-the-difference-between-look-see-and-watch)

Answer (score 4):

In OP's example either could be used, and it's unlikely many speakers would be aware of any difference, regardless of the *exact* supporting context.

To give a clearer indication of where many people *would* make a distinction, consider...

> Tommy [playing on the rug in front of the TV]:
>    *"I'm a fire engine! Nee-naw, nee-naw!"*
>    Dad:
>    *"Will you be quiet, Tommy! Me and Mum are trying to **watch** the movie!"*

...where virtually no native speaker would use ***see***. Although somewhat curiously, if it had been ***the news*** rather than ***a movie***, I think quite a few (still a minority) might be prepared to use ***see***.

---

Or an even clearer distinction...

> Tracey [Tommy's older sister, on the phone]:
>    *"Can you come and pick me up from the station, Dad?"*
>    Dad:
>    *"I'm just **watching** the news, but I'll be there in 20 minutes"*

...where I think *no* native speaker would ever use ***see***, for a movie *or* the news.

On the other hand, if I cast my mind back to [9/11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks), it's quite possible I had a phone conversation along the lines of...

Caller:
 *"You'll never believe what's happened! Turn on your TV!"*
 FumbleFingers [for it is he]:
 *"I'm **seeing** the news right now! I'm stunned!"*

---

There's some useful information about the differences between the "troublesome trio" ***watch, see,*** and ***look*** [here at EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-see-look-watch.htm) (a site specifically aimed at non-native learners), including...

> *[**seeing**] may not be deliberate. As soon as we open our eyes, we see things*
>    ***watch*** is much more active. It's like **look**, but requires more effort from us.
>    *In general, we use **see** for public performances and **watch** for television at home*

But I wouldn't attach *too* much importance to the last point. Apart from anything else, I suspect it mainly derives from the fact that public performances are generally less under the viewer's control (you ***see*** them because they're "there", and your eyes are open). In the privacy of your own home you make a positive effort to load a DVD, and you have personal control (*pause, mute,* etc. on the remote control). So there's often more "active involvement" (the second point above).

Comment: Interesting. When you're in the theater (present tense), you're always _watching_ the movie. But, when talking about the movie in the past or furture, _see_ works just fine. ("We _saw_ Cinderella last weekend." Or, "I've got free tickets to the theater; what movie do you want to go _see_?") It's all utterly natural for the native speaker, but I can see how it could confound the learner!

Comment: @J.R. I think your explanation is better regarding the difference between *watch* and *see*. You should write an answer that way.

Comment: @J.R., user3169: I got called away before I could add something about *why* we sometimes significantly favour one verb over another, but I've added a bit now.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to understand that *watch* and *see* bear the same relation as *listen* and *hear*. The first term in each pair implies an active relation: the person is in some sense paying attention to the stimulus. Seeing and hearing can be more passive.

I may hear a plane pass overhead, but if I'm not paying attention to it then you might say that I am not really listening to it.

Of course, at some level you cannot hear if you do not listen, and you cannot see if you do not watch - to some extent. It is a matter of degree. Paying little attention, especially conscious attention, versus paying close attention, especially thinking about what you are watching or listening to.