# Can I use the continuous aspect in the past and present tense?

Tags: grammar, progressive-aspect, past-continuous

Is the following sentence correct?

> "Has Sarah been watching us this entire time?"

And can you say **"Sarah is watching"** when it comes to watching people?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Had you any questions about how things work here, please take some of your time to visit [the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help). || I take that your question is regarding *watch*. Please take a look at [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53693/watch-movie-x-vs-see-movie-x?s=1|1.5907) then.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to 'watching people', is it correct? *Certainly!*

One can *watch* people.

> She watched the kids playing in the yard

...says [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/watch_1?q=watch).

That said, *Sarah has been watching you for the entire time*.

Comment: note that he said _the_ entire time, not _this_ entire time. ("this" would be grammatical, but not the usual way to say it)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock you mean 'the entire time' is ungrammatical?

Comment: Absolutely not. I was pointing out to OP to notice your _improvement_ of the original!